# Navigation error "Platform view cannot be found" in MAUI NET8

Tags: c#, maui

I read a few posts in here about this subject but I can't find an answer to my question.

The scenario is common. When the application starts, it has to check if the authentication is required. If I need the authentication, it displays the *LoginPage* if not the *MainPage*. I moved all the router dependencies in the *App.xaml.cs* for example

```
public App(UserSettings settings, IServiceProvider services)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoginPage), typeof(LoginPage));

    if (settings.UseBiometric || settings.IsPasswordRequired)
    {
        var page = services.GetService<LoginPage>();
        MainPage = page;
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

With this configuration, without calling the *AppShell*, I have to rewrite the navigation between pages. So, after the authentication, I open the *MainPage* like

```
var page = services.GetService<MainPage>();
Application.Current.MainPage = page;
```

From the *MainPage*, I open other pages using the same method, for example, to navigate to the *DictionaryList*, I use

```
var page = services.GetService<DictionaryList>();
_ = Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, true);
```

On this page, I can call other pages such as *FlashCard*. To remove the page, I use this code

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

If I pop this *FlashCard* page and reopen it, I get this error

> Platform view cannot be found

[image]

[image]

What is the best practice and/or correct implementation of the navigation?

PS: all the pages have some dependency injection

Comment: Did you register the page route in appshell?

Comment: Yes, in fact I open the page using the route

Comment: Can you provide a demo I can reproduce?